# Recommendations for Express and Socket.io for chat app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, socket.io

I am building a website that has a list of chats with node + express + mysql for the backend and the frontend is react.

I want the chat to be realtime, so I added socket.io. Currently this is the order of things that happen when a user sends a message

user hits send button -> post request to express api to add message to mysql database -> socket.io sends an 'chat update' message to clients -> on 'chat update' make a get request to express api to fetch the chat messages again

However, there is a noticeable delay when I hit send and the chat refreshes. Should I use socket.io to handle all the communication within the chat not just server -> client?

Comment: if you use socket.io you simply broadcast the message, there is no need to ask the database... the client will have a message history as long as they keep the browser window open... if you want to have messages before the time the client connects, then add a `load previous...` action and fetch the previous `n` messages since `now`... BTW, going RDS way it will be painful if you really going to take that chat into production, loon into NoSql database, they will be way faster and cheaper.

Comment: Let me see if I understand what you are saying.
client emits to server -> server emits to clients and writes to database asynchronously -> client receive the new message and appends to current messages

Isn't there a chance that messages will be out of order then depending on the connection speed fo the server -> client emit since we are not using a ground truth (the database)?

Comment: if you thinking about "message sync" then I think you're missing the point of sockets, and for logging messages, I assume for moderating proposes, you should just dump into a file per day/hour per channel ... using a database for holding such data will became expensive in no time!

Comment: If I write to the database once every hour for a chat then wouldn't that mean any new users that join the chat can't see any messages from the last hour?

Comment: why would users want to know what was written 1h ago? what's the point? a chat is a real-time conversation ... if you're trying to do what Slack does, then you would be better by using a NoSql DB (cheaper and much faster than an RDS) and have that button/link/scroll up to load previous messages... then again, I really don't know what your solution is all about.